# Proper way to restart vsphere services on esxi 5 host?

Tags: vmware-esxi

At $WORK, we recently moved from VMWare Server to ESXi 5.  The Vsphere client connects to port 443 (SSL) on the server, and uses the originally generated ssl cert from the install.

I've replaced the rui.key and rui.crt files with our usual wildcard SSL cert, using the ssh interface to the ESXi server.  Now, I need to restart whatever services on the ESXi host which provide access to the Vsphere client.

Does anyone have any idea about how to do this without rebooting the machine entirely?  It seems like maybe restarting hostd with /etc/init.d/hostd restart would do it, but I don't want to accidentally bounce all the VM's, so I want to know for sure.

I'm really looking for the same functionality as the "Restart Management Agents" from the console, but via an ssh command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this KB here:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005566

There is a CLI command that will restart the management agents. Obviously SSH will need to be enabled.

Comment: Cheers.  I had somehow missed the lines about esxi!

Answer (score 0):

On VMWare 6.x, you can restart the reverse proxy.

On the shell (likely over SSH):

```
/etc/init.d/rhttpproxy restart
```